# Should I delete my question if suspected it's a bug by the library?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

Should I delete my question if I suspect it cannot be solved (yet) due to a bug by the library itself or I suspect no one would answer such question?

Please see my following 2 posts:

- [Crosswalk Cordova - js alert shows block characters on Chinese interface android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466072/crosswalk-cordova-js-alert-shows-block-characters)
- [Node-Webkit - Try enumerate file under directory from webkitdirectory input but return only directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800822/node-webkit-try-enumerate-file-under-directory-from-webkitdirectory-input-but)

After many days of research after posting the questions, I now suspect that they could be bugs by the libraries' author and no straight answers would be found **except for any tricks** that go around the situations.

Should I delete them? Because I heard deleting questions may be harmful.

**Or should I answer them myself? But they are really not relevant answers to the question.**

Comment: If you *know* that it's due to bugs in the library you're using, I think posting a self-answer would be a better idea (contrary to popular belief, this is a legitimate answer). If you merely *suspect* it though, I'd leave it alone.

Comment: You can offer a bounty to get attention so that someone will answer it. I don't see any reason to delete them.

Comment: Someone will probably post an identical question right after you delete yours (if you choose to).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

No, you should not delete such a question.  If it is a bug in a library then it is pretty likely that you are not the only programmer that gets bitten by that bug.  And the need for a workaround is a high one.  Even a seemingly unhelpful answer that states something like "Version x.y solves the problem" is valuable, it tells any other victim to update the library.

Show your evidence in the question, it helps others to skip research steps to find a workaround.

Comment: As an addition, linking to the issue in the bug-tracker, especially if not yet resolved, is a good idea. If neccessary after creating it yourself (probably also containing a back-link to the SO question).

Comment: Just like I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28971463/4428462).

Comment: Ditto. Pls dont delete. Plenty of newbies that will befenit as well as the actual library maintainers.

Comment: Surely there are *some* circumstances in which such questions should be deleted? For instance, what if the bug was only present in one minor release, was fixed in trunk, and will be completely irrelevant next week?

Comment: +1 I can't even count how many node.js bug posts exactly like this that've helped me. Most are something like _"update to x.y.z"_ which seems simple but, I will +1 all day considering that I don't closely follow the project and someone else dug through the code/issues to find that.

Comment: @RyneEverett Even then, I don't think the question should be deleted. Just answer it with "This was fixed in trunk and will be released next week," ideally along with relevant information about the commit that fixed it. Just because a release next week will fix it doesn't mean the _question_ will be irrelevant next week. Not everyone upgrades weekly.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! I did answer my question on node-webkit and I'll wait for Cordova :)

Comment: @RyneEverett As reirab says, *someone* will happen to be on that version even ten years from now. Just assume that every single version of every library is in use somewhere out there. That said, for a short-lived minor version of a library, the fact that it's limited to that version should be immediately obvious. That way people who are on a different version can get back to Google and looking for relevant results as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 8):

That might be the best kind of question. I had a similar issue and [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179364/propel-postgresql-migration-unable-to-find-adapter) I made has since become my most popular question on SO. Other people will realize they are not crazy when it's a confirmed bug, it will increase awareness for the library maintainers, it will help you find a workaround, and it will let other people know which version of the library is affected.