# Should I delete this question if it was related to bug in the library itself?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently asked a question [Unable to find iPad Pro iOS 10 device using Cordova for emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494985/unable-to-find-ipad-pro-ios-10-device-using-cordova-for-emulation) which was a bug in the library and within a day, the author of the library fixed & released its new version.

So should I delete this question (as it doesn't have any answer and up/down votes)?

(One user [asked me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494985/unable-to-find-ipad-pro-ios-10-device-using-cordova-for-emulation#comment68293231_40494985) to delete the question as well on the comment)

Comment: Closely related: [Should I delete my question if suspected it's a bug by the library?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290082/3853934)

Comment: Yes @Gothdo, I found that question but the author of that question was not sure if that is a bug so I was curious to ask this question

Comment: If the bug has been fixed in a new version, I suppose you could post a self-answer explaining that the solution is to upgrade to that new version.

Comment: On the one hand I can see self answering so if someone else using that version has the same problem they will know what to do.  On the other hand what are the chances of someone getting that outdated version and hitting that same problem.  I certainly would not vote to close or deleted if it was self answered.  Just not sure how useful it would be.

Comment: Thanks @Gothdo & Nathan, I agree. I used to self answer and accept in such cases but I got confused when the user asked me to delete. I'll do the same again

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you should answer the question, explain the situation and (if available) point the users to a fixed version. This way you can help others who have the same problem as you.

In some cases a bug can go unfixed for years, and if it's in a popular library, a lot of people will be thankful. There's been a bug in the Bootstrap customiser for a few years now, and the answer has gathered nearly 400 upvotes over time.

Comment: Thanks Stijn. I used to do it in the same way, [example1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130950/user-authentication-failing-after-upgrading-to-3-2-1), [example2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202523/render-a-template-as-string-in-a-service-in-grails-3-rest-api-profile-app). I just got confused when the user asked me to delete the post.