# How should GitHub issues (mentioned in the answers) be tracked?

Tags: discussion, github

Let's say there's a question describing a bug, asking for guidance (what happened?) and/or help (how should I fix this?)

Let's also say someone tracked that bug to an open issue on the corresponding framework/package/library GitHub - and found out there's no cure at the moment, and no real workarounds are available.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326181/http-server-gives-warning-message) is an example: an issue is known, but no open PR is registered.

Now, while [the acceptable solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337697/should-i-delete-this-question-if-it-was-related-to-bug-in-the-library-itself) is to answer with an explanation linking to those GitHub issues, I find it a bit... insufficient. The problem is, when the issue (finally!) becomes resolved, there'll be no way to track that status within the answer - other than rechecking the links manually, of course.

Is it possible to connect those somehow? To make issues' statuses trackable in Stack Overflow answers - for example, by adding a specific icon showing status of that issue?

Or should we just close these questions whatsoever, as their answers are essentially duplicates of the corresponding GitHub issue pages?

Comment: We definitely shouldn't close the question; we don't close questions as being duplicates of things outside the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: As someone who has answered some questions linking to bug report, I try to update the answer if there's new significant info from the thread. I agree the problem with outdated information is real, but it's not strictly to bug report. I don't think we need additional feature for this; editing and updating the answer is sufficient.

Comment: On other sites, bugs on Linux and derivatives are closed and asked to direct their questions to the bug tracker. SE is a terrible bug tracker and the only way we make sure bugs are reported is that developers are informed about them.

Comment: @Braiam i think the focus is not on tracking the bug on SE, but to keep the answer up to date with the latest information on the issue. Question is surely to be kept open, I would just make sure to have a reference to the last released version of the library/application in the answer, so that when the bug is resolved it can be edited to say "resolved in version x.x.x" etc.

Comment: @bracco23 that's way too much work for the community. Questions aren't preferred to be time sensitive. If a bug was fixed, who is going to find it useful?

Comment: @braiam It depends, what if I bug was fixed for a specific release but the release you have has this issue? Finding a question on [so] that point's to the cause and how it was fixed could be helpful even if it just means you update what release you are using.

Comment: Also, questions and answers have to balance being useful when they are written and being useful in the future. Just like Wikipedia, they should be written to be time-independent, meaning that one should be able to read it from any point in time and find it useful, hence the reference to the actual revision and, in the update from somebody in the future that finds it and discovers that the bug is fixed, the reference to the minimum version of the fix.

Comment: Maybe related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373675/at-what-point-do-we-move-from-so-to-github-issue

Comment: @Lankymart finding the SO post is the most unhelpful result. The bug tracker should be the first result. SO participation at that point should be null.

Comment: It's far from unhelpful to find a post that cites and links to the issue, @Braiam . What would be unhelpful would be finding a post that says "That currently doesn't work, due to a big." with no citation or link.

Comment: I sometime leave a comment on the Github issue linking to the SO question. It makes the dev aware there is a need for this bug to be fixed, and maybe they will come back to the question after  the fix to edit it.

Comment: @Larnu that's the thing, complains should be directed to the developer of the library/compiler/etc. Or people would start using other tool that allows them to do the task they are set to do.

Comment: Asking *how* to do something, and demonstrating your attempt to complete that isn't a complaint, @Braiam . That's an on-topic question. If the answer to the question is "because of an application flaw", then that doesn't make the question off-topic. The answer to an on-topic question doesn't, by definition, make a question off-topic.

Comment: @Larnu asking "how to do something with X" is ok. Following the manual of X and not obtaining the result that the manual said it should is not a question for SO. It's a bug report. If python says that 2+2 should print 4 but instead prints 5, you aren't asking how to sum 2+2, but why the result doesn't follow logic. Those are the kind of questions I'm talking about, clear bugs.

Comment: *"Following the manual of X and not obtaining the result that the manual said it should is not a question for SO. "* you would be surprised how many times people say they have "followed the documentation" and they haven't, or have misinterpreted it, @Braiam . This question isn't about making bug reports, you're misunderstanding the intent.

Comment: @Larnu "Let's also say someone **tracked that bug to an open issue** on the corresponding framework/package/library GitHub" Yes, we are. I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: The ***answerer*** @Braiam, *not* the question asker... Again, an answer to a question that is on topic does not make a difference question off topic.

Comment: @Larnu Again, if something is a bug, it should be reported as a bug. I don't care which got the wrong idea (the answerer, the asker, the observer, etc.), those questions do not belong here.

Comment: So, to confirm your opinion, @Braiam, if someone asks a good on topic question, it should be deleted if the reason they can't do what they want to is due to a bug..? I disagree, but I would like to see you put that into an answer for others to vote on.

Comment: @Larnu no, I told you already what's a bug. Something that has an issue on the bug tracker which developer acknowledged.

Comment: I feel what ever opinion you're trying to convey here is being lost in translation, @Braiam, and it seems like your contradicting yourself. Posting an answer, with your thoughts, will likely solve any confusion.

Answer (score 36):

Certainly we (the community) shouldn't be closing the question based on the fact that there is an Issue on GitHub about the problem. Provided that the question is still on topic for Stack Overflow, and meets other requirements of the site (such as providing an MRE should it be required) then the question is perfectly valid for the site. The fact the the problem, at the time it was posted, cannot be solved due to a flaw in the application is not the fault of the asker, nor Stack Overflow; if it's a good question then upvote it!

As for the answer, in my opinion, making an answer that references and cites an existing Issue on GitHub (or similar service) in the answer is also a good answer. Likely the Issue, if it's been accepted by the 3rd party developer as a actual flaw, might even have details of why it's happening too; though just because it's known *why* it's happening doesn't mean it's easily fixed. This is important information for the OP of the question, and it explains why what they want to do (at the time) doesn't work. Telling someone they *can't* do something for XY reasons is still an answer, even if that answer isn't what the person wants to hear.

As for updating, that too isn't required. At best it's a "nice to have", but I don't see any need to automate it. The link to the Issue is in the question, and you can subscribe to that Issue if knowing when it is resolved is important. If more people are subscribed, or "upvote" the Issue, then it also informs the developer how many people it's effecting which might improve the focus the problem gets. If future readers are having the same problem, and it's still not resolved, they can do the same. The important thing is that their question has also been answered as they have been given evidence as to why what they want to do isn't working.

Finally, if a PR is completed and fixes the problem, the issue would be closed, citing said PR. If a future user then has the problem and visits the question, they can see the Issue has been closed, and in what PR. They can then check if they are running a version that includes that PR and update as required (as likely they aren't). They too have had the answer to their problem: to fix the problem you need to update to version xyz or above. If the person wants, they can make an edit (request) for the answer as well, to note the problem is solved in a specific PR, so that future readers can consume that information without visiting Github.

Comment: "If the person wants, they can make an edit (request) for the answer as well": I find that comments are more typical; a few of my older answers linked to bug trackers, and (much) later people have commented to say that the bug has been fixed (or at least changed in some way). Then I update the answer (usually keeping the original for context). And as a reader if I find an answer with a link to a bug or other resource, I always check the bug for more up-to-date information, which I think is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Given that a major part of Stack Overflow is that it's intended to be a "best answer to good question X" and in achieving that aim we're all responsible in curating the content, it seems logical that it could be well answered like any other "answered externally here" question; namely to copy significant relevant parts of that external resource locally, and explain and link the external resource...

..but also, given the time-dependent nature of the link and that the external resource may update independently of Stack Overflow, I'd suggest imploring future readers to keep the answer as up to date as they can, if they find the situation has changed

- Post up a community-wiki answer - it's the very spirit of a CW answer that it be given over to the community to curate and improve. People seem averse to editing other people's posts on Stack Overflow, but I believe CW can alleviate that psychologically
- State that it's a known issue, tracked at (link) caused by (precis/bit more detail)
- Say something like "at the time of posting this answer the truth was X, but if you hit this answer in the future and the situation has changed, please update it - I'm making it CW to hopefully encourage this"

I don't think this needs a "there should be an automated solution" - if literally everyone who landed on the question here first (rather than on the relevant GitHub repository) and saw an answer saying "as of 2009 this was a bug with ... but please help out by updating this answer if you get things working/that bug is resolved" and they did then perform that update, then the answer would stay as up to date as it needed to be to serve the "I prefer to get my answers from Stack Overflow" crowd.

Answer (score -1):

If an answer to a question on Stack Overflow is "it's a bug in the version of the dependency you're using, here's a link to a bug on an issue tracker" then that question has no intrinsic value for anyone, except as a signpost to the actual bug.

Any other answers to said question add zero value because the only correct answer is to update to a fixed version of the dependency, which is implied by the link to the bug. You might argue that answers that suggest workarounds are valuable, to which my response would be that said answers are likely to be hacks, and unsafe ones at that, which are liable to cause other problems down the line. Given the propensity of users of this site to blindly copy-paste code without thinking about it, we should actively avoid that sort of content.

In short, **these questions should be closed with a link to the bug on the issue tracker in question**. Essentially they are a subset of duplicate questions, except the canonical dupe target in this case is the issue tracker link.

There isn't a need for new UI for this, we can simply use the current `close > community-specific > other` flow and put the link to the bug in the close comment.

Comment: BTW, on other sites, we try hard for the issue in the tracker to be the first thing they find, so we actively delete these questions and move relevant information to the bug report.

Comment: *"put the link to the bug in the close comment."* Comments can be deleted at any time though (even if that comment has 100's of upvotes); if the comment is deleted then the value is completely lost. Comments should neither provide required information to complete a question or answer.

Comment: Well @Larnu, the chance of SE Inc. updating the UI to cater to this specific case is less than a snowball's in hell, so all we can do is work with the tools we have.

Comment: My point is that, if anywhere, it would therefore be better to have the information in an answer; as the the information can't be deleted on a whim.